# Basis of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Find a basis of the subspace <$x^2-x+4,x-1,x^2+x$> of the vector space $P_2$ over $\mathbb R$.

I formed a matrix where the first row was $ 4, -1, 0 $, the second row was $ -1, 1, 1$ and the final row was $ 1, 0, 1$. I reduced this to reduced echelon form and obtained the identity matrix. Does that mean those $3$ polynomials already form a basis of $P_2$?

Comment: If the matrix reduces to $I$ then yes, they are linearly independent and they must also span the space, so they then form a basis.

Comment: @Xetrov Can you check my answer to make sure it actually does though and I set the matrix up correctly?

Comment: @Dam ask a computer to double check the answer instead. They're more reliable than people.

Comment: Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?

Answer (score -1):

where
�
α,
�
β, and
�
γ are real numbers. Equate coefficients of corresponding terms on both sides and solve for
�
α,
�
β, and
�
γ. If you can find values for
�
α,
�
β, and
�
γ for any arbitrary polynomial in
�
2
P
2
​
, then the set is a basis for
�
2
P
2
​
.

If you can successfully express any polynomial in
�
2
P
2
​
as a linear combination of the given polynomials, then the set
{
�
2
−
�
+
4
,
�
−
1
,
�
2
+
�
}
{x
2
−x+4,x−1,x
2
+x} forms a basis for
�
2
P
2
​
. If not, then it does not form a basis.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).